# Advertencia de validación de esquema: No se ha declarado el elemento 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2:UBLExte

Tags: c#

estoy intentando generar una clase C# a partir de un XSD (El cual descargue de SUNAT), pero al intentar hacerlo mediante consola de desarrollador del Visual Studio 2015, me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Como se ve en la imagen, estos son algunas de las advertencias que me bota al intentar generarlo.]

Comment: Por favor agrega el error como texto y no como una imagen. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Answer (score 0):

Para generar una clase C# a partir de un XSD, una opción es utilizar la herramienta xsd.exe que viene incluida con el entorno de desarrollo de Visual Studio. Para utilizar esta herramienta, primero debes abrir la consola de desarrollador del Visual Studio y luego ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
xsd <nombre_del_archivo_xsd> /c
```

Este comando generará un archivo de clase C# con el nombre especificado en el archivo XSD. Por ejemplo, si el archivo XSD se llama "mi_esquema.xsd", el comando anterior generaría un archivo de clase C# llamado "mi_esquema.cs".

Si te encuentras con el error que mencionas, una posible solución es utilizar la opción /u en lugar de /c en el comando xsd. Esto indicará a la herramienta que genere clases de utilidad en lugar de clases de tipo. Por ejemplo:

```
xsd <nombre_del_archivo_xsd> /u
```

Otra opción es utilizar una herramienta en línea como xsd2code. Esta herramienta te permite subir un archivo XSD y luego generar un archivo de clase C# a partir de él.

Para utilizar xsd2code, solo tienes que seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Accede a la página de xsd2code en https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/.
2. Haz clic en el botón "Choose File" y selecciona el archivo XSD que deseas utilizar.
3. Configura las opciones de la herramienta según tus necesidades (p. ej., el nombre de la clase, el espacio de nombres, etc.).
4. Haz clic en el botón "Generate" para generar el archivo de clase C#.
   Descarga el archivo de clase C# generado y utilízalo en tu proyecto de C#.

Espero que esta opción te resulte útil. Si tienes alguna duda, no dudes en volver a preguntar. ¡Buena suerte!